# Old Syfy channel movie that involved creatures that were good at camouflage

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I remember watching a movie on the Syfy channel a few years back, and it had these creatures with wings like a butterfly or moth that allowed them to camouflage into the pine forest. I can't remember the name of the movie and would appreciate the help. The one scene I can remember was one of the creatures was cloaked against a tree when a larger man passed by. I think he was doing some kind of surveying and it attacked him. I thought it was the Mothman movies but it wasn't. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A real long shot here as you haven't indicated if this was a sword & sorcery type of movie or more pure science fiction. But, could it be one of the bird men from BeastMaster?

Though they are called bird men their wings are more like a butterfly or maybe a bat (please see picture below). The YouTube videoclip shows a man running past some shrubs/trees and he gets nabbed by one of them.  Anything look familiar?

[YouTube VideoClip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0c4Y61UpWOg)

[image: Beastmaster Birdmen]